# ruby initialize method arguments mismatch

Tags: ruby, class, activerecord, arguments, sinatra

I'm writing an app in Sinatra, using activerecord, so I guess my question is the same as in Rails.

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base

    require 'date'
    belongs_to :bankaccount

end


class Recurrent < Entry

    attr_accessor :date_1, :date_2, :monthly_entry

    def initialize (date_1, date_2)
        @date_1 = date_1 # format DateTime.new(2020,12,5) 
        @date_2 = date_2
    end

    # other methods
```

When I run this code, I get :

```
>> date_1 = DateTime.new(2020,12,5)
>> date_2 = DateTime.new(2021,11,5)
>> recurrent = Recurrent.new(date_1, date_2)
**ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1))**
```

and when I remove the arguments, I get this error message:

```
>> recurrent = Recurrent.new
**ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2))**
```

When I do this in plain ruby and run it in irb, so without activerecord, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html):

> ## Creation
>
> Active Records accept constructor parameters either in a hash or as a block. The hash method is especially useful when you're receiving the data from somewhere else, like an HTTP request. It works like this:
>
> ```ruby
> user = User.new(name: "David", occupation: "Code Artist")
> user.name # => "David"
> ```
>
> You can also use block initialization:
>
> ```ruby
> user = User.new do |u|
>   u.name = "David"
>   u.occupation = "Code Artist"
> end
> ```
>
> And of course you can just create a bare object and specify the attributes after the fact:
>
> ```ruby
> user = User.new
> user.name = "David"
> user.occupation = "Code Artist"
> ```

So, `ActiveRecord` objects allow three different kinds of creating them:

- No argument, set attributes later.
- Block argument.
- One `Hash` argument.

They don't allow two arguments.